# How to assign the checkbox value in action link in a cshtml page from another cshtml page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

Code:

Index.cshtml

```
<div class ="">
    <input id="date" type="checkbox" />Date<br /><br />
</div>
```

Header.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Action", "Controller", new 
                                {date = ??}, new
                {
                    @class = "hidden",
                    @Id = "tasks"
                })
```

How to assign the checkbox value in action link in **date** parameter(true(if checked) or false(if not checked)) in a cshtml page from another cshtml page?

Comment: Explain clearly what you want to achieve. You can add date to ViewBag in your controller and then take it to assign in another page. Is that what you want to ask?

Comment: yes, that also ok for me. How to acheive that?

Comment: In post method of your index.cshtml take that date value and then put it in the ViewBag.MyDate = ... after that you can use it in header.cshtml like date = @ViewBag.MyDate if you use razor engine. If header.cshtml is in another controller however, you have to put the date in TempData since ViewBag is controller dependent but TempData is stored in session

Comment: Can you post as a clear answer below, then it will be understand easily for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a form and the html helper for checkbox

like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(action, controller, FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.date)
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Then in your post action, the date will be available in your posted model.